# How to prepare a non-flush door lining for re-skimming without replacing it

Tags: doors, plaster, carpentry, door-frame

We are having a room in our house re-skimmed in a couple of weeks, and I've recently removed the old architrave around the bedroom door due to its poor condition.
After removing the architrave, I noticed that the door lining is not flush with the existing wall; it sits about 1 cm back from the wall when compared against a level.

I would like to know the best way to prepare this door lining for the plasterer without having to replace it entirely. Part of the reason I don't want to replace the entire door lining is because the existing door is a non-standard size but is a nice old Victorian door.

Is there a method or material I can use to bridge the gap and ensure a flush surface for the new plaster?

**Images**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this is usually fixed is to use a table saw to rip thin stips of wood off the edge of a fine quality pine board. Ideally the thickness of this board is the same as the thickness of the boards that make up your door jamb. The board must be long as or a little longer than the height of your door jamb.

These strips are then attached to the edges of the jamb to bring the jamb out even with the re-skimmed wall surface. (Clearly why these strips are called jamb extensions). Obviously the size of the strip is selected to make this extension to the jamb the right amount.

Before attaching the strips you will need to carefully clean up the jamb edge removing any remaining nails, paint ridges and other materials stuck to the wood. You also want to very carefully line up the visible edges of these strips with the existing jamb face so when you sand and re-paint there is a nice smooth surface there.

Comment: And wait til the skimming is complete, so you know how far your jamb needs to extend!

Comment: @Huesmann - I already alluded to the point you are trying to make.... "These strips are then attached to the edges of the jamb to bring the jamb out even **with the re-skimmed wall surface**."